# Option Infer ON

Tags: vba, option-infer

Does option infer not work in VBA?

I'm try to test out VB tutorial code on arrays in Microsoft Access.

```
Dim numbers = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

This doesn't work without Option Infer ON, but you get compile error if you add it in.

Total noob question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Option Infer` directive is a feature added to VB.Net in Visual Studio 2008.  The VBA compiler is a completely different implementation that was never updated for `Option Infer` hence there is no way to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this post; though `Option Infer` is not present, in VBA you can still turn `Option Explicit` *off* which gives you a poor mans version. Be careful, however, as this isn't truly `Option Infer`. What you're doing is simply making VBA primarily use variants to store the values. The VBA engine then decides what the best subtype of variant is. For example:

```
Dim a, b
a = 2
b = 3.2
Debug.Print a * b
```

Will work quite happily.  However, you can then go on to change the value later, like so...

```
Dim a, b
a = 2
b = 3.2
Debug.Print a * b
a = "Hello, World!"
Debug.Print a
```

Which works quite happily and produces the output:

```
 6.4
Hello, World!
```

Not the best practice.

## Revision

Just to further reinforce the poor quality of this approach, I have had several experiences where the *[original programmer's]* code has happily crashed, bringing down the whole application, because variables were not properly defined.

Comment: A downvote for explaining alternatives and then going on to say that it's not a good practice?...  Wow! Tough crowd!

Comment: Given that the OP was in a VBA environment I think this is at least a reasonable approach. Judicious code comments could make it perfectly usable.